# Python, sqlalchemy, Select with WHERE IN clause

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using Python and sqlalchemy:

How can I achieve the following MySQL statement with a WHERE ... IN clause using a tuple?

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (symbol, volume) IN (('ES', 238 ),('GB', 500 ),('OH', 800 ));`

in sqlalchemy **core** (ie **not** the ORM version)

I looked in the documentation and generally on SO/google, this is nowhere to be found...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading this part of the documentation -
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.in_

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you use the declarative style (i.e. ORM classes). For your table there should be a orm class. I am assuming it as MyTable. Then the code will be like this:

```
keys = [
    ('ES', 238 ),('GB', 500 ),('OH', 800 )
]

select([
    MyTable.url
]).select_from(
    MyTable
).where(
    tuple_(MyTable.symbol, MyTable.volume).in_(keys)
)
```

Comment: @A H M Forhadul Islam This is not useful as it deters other users from posting the right answer. I clearly stated in my question (in bold) that I am not interested in the orm. You might leave your answer though, as it might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy import tuple_
stmt = select([mytable]).where(tuple_(mytable.c.symbol,mytable.c.volume)
                               .in_([('ES',238),('GB',500),('OH',800)]))
```